# How does gZip and DEFLATE actually work?

Tags: php, gzip

I am using the following lines in my .htaccess file:

```
####################
# GZIP COMPRESSION #
####################
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

I have tested, via browser tools, that it is working and enabled.

Very dumb question here... but do I have to actually compress the files and serve up a gzip file to actually make this work?

Or does this just happen while the resources are consumed by the browser?

Comment: You don't have to gzip it manually, web server does it for you. That's why you have `AddOutputFilterByType ` which tells Apache what exactly to compress, and upon successful compression - it adds the appropriate header so browser knows that it has to decompress the contents before showing it to you.

Comment: Voted down because no research done.

Comment: Michael is grumpy today. Thanks Mjh.

Answer (score 3):

Apache module [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html) does the compression for you.

It is an *output filter* which will compress data before sending it to the client, depending on whether the client can actually understand the compression (this is negotiated).

Comment: jjmontes so after running a few tests, I still see that some files are noted as "still should be compressed."  Why are these files not being served as compressed? is it becuase of the file extensions? ".min.js"
http://summerlawnsinc.com/css/style-desktop.css
http://summerlawnsinc.com/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js
http://summerlawnsinc.com/js/skel.min.js
http://summerlawnsinc.com/js/skel-layers.min.js

Comment: Check those files are being served with a mime type that matches your settings (`text/html text/css text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php`). Check you are not hitting one of your exceptions (ie MSIE or Mozilla/4). Check your browser is not using cached versions of those resources (hit CTRL+F5, or clear your cache).

Answer (score 0):

The files should be compressed in the server "on the fly". You can check it viewing the response http header `Content-Encoding`. It should have the value `gzip` that indicates that the file was compressed on the server side and uncompressed on the client side (obviously, if it wasn't the file won't make sense for the browser)